# cors issue when integrated stripe payment gateway in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe payment gateway in my react project but cors  related issue occur.
Can any one help me to resolve this.

"Access to fetch at 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

But it works fine when I am disabling the cors in chrome browser. Is there any alternate how to integrate stripe payment gateway in reactjs project?

My code:

```
      const bodyFormData = new FormData()
      bodyFormData.append("client_secret", "");
      bodyFormData.append("code", code);
      bodyFormData.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");

      fetch("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData),
        headers:{
        Accept:'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':"*",
        OPTIONS: '',
        }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
        resolve(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       reject(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making that call [to complete the connection](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#post-token) from frontend React code in a browser. You can't do that and it will never work, since it uses your Stripe secret key which should never be on the frontend.

Instead you should make this call from a backend server route after the user is redirected from the OAuth page.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am using aws lambda function as backend and integrate aws api in my react code. so how we call stripe completion connection api from aws. Is there any other solution so i call stripe api from react fetch.

Comment: @AshvindSharma did you ever find a solution for this problem?